# Feeling a little bullied etc. by a moderator

Tags: discussion

Is it OK for mods to lock things merely because they have invested enough time in the site to be a mod? No of course not!

Isn't that exactly what CriglCragl has said here?

[Humanity is vermin: prove me wrong](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92865/humanity-is-vermin-prove-me-wrong?noredirect=1#comment263171_92865)

**What else could he be saying?** It seems the best explanation (which unfortunately is all I really have to go on in the entire exchange). It could be that he thinks I am not worth him engaging with, and so is encouraging others to do likewise. I would strongly discourage that sort of moderation also: I am a viable PSE poster, thanks :-)

The fact they are a moderator does not mean it is not "group think" and mindless conformity. I am honestly kinda upset by the whole business now.

**Is it OK for moderators to use their reputation etc. to encourage other users of the site to make a pariah of another user?** Isn't that kinda bullying?

I'm *sorry* for the poor question, however.

Comment: ah I'm the worst person alive. sorry if I'm a nuisance :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok for mods to lock the comments the moment where they do not discuss how to improve the question but derail into personal exchanges. The system suggests when I look into the possible reasons for a lock at the option "comments only" the following:

> Lock the comments on this post if the discussion is no longer contributing to its improvement. Users will still be able to interact with this post in all other ways.

This is exactly what has happened here. This has nothing to do with the time we spent here. There are users who contributed much longer than me or Geoffrey. We stood up for election when elections were held, got most of the votes, and accepted the vote. We are regular users who got these privileges because the community chose and supported us getting these privileges.

That being said, you can always ask for clarification regarding moderation decisions. I would ask to be less accusing and polemic and rather just asking what happened and why things were decided that way. Then the reception would certainly be more positive as well.